# Different date formats in single column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am using SQL server. We have `date` column in table but some of them are stored in different format.

For e.g: We have records with format `2015-12-09 00:00:12.000` but some records are there with format as `2015/09/09 00:08:09.000` or any other valid date type.
How can I identify records with different date format from table.
I tried using `isdate()` function but as all date are valid there is no luck.
Can you please guide me with this.

Comment: Yes,but DB is handled by client and insert is taken care by them, I am trying to rectify the issue now. :(

Comment: just to be clear, the `date` column in in fact type `varchar` not `date` ?

Comment: @Utsav - Its of type date.....I am also thinking about casting the date column and find the '/' character to identify dates with '/' format as major dates are available in '-' format.

Comment: I am not sure about SQL Sever, the dates are stored in same format in DB if they are of type date. The difference in view may be due to your client settings. Can you edit your question and show some example how are you seeing different date format by same client?

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Either you have `varchar` column, than you can use `like` to find what you want, or you have a `date` column and than you cannot have format problem. Maybe you are not specific enough.

Comment: The column available have datatype as datetime, and this table is populated by ETL by client team. They are allowing insert in different valid date format like '2015-01-14 00:09:09.000' and '2015/03/23 00:00:34.000'. Although date separated by '/' are low but those cause issues with my other applications so I am trying to identify such records with different formats.. Hope this helps to understand issue.

Comment: Just to add note, the format will be same like 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS.SSS' only separator will be different. So need to find records with different separators.

Comment: You say, the datatype is `datetime` and that means, it does not matter how is the data inserted, the result format will always be the same: `create table aaa (d datetime); insert into aaa (d) values ('2015-01-14 00:09:09.000'); insert into aaa (d) values ('2015/03/23 00:00:34.000'); select d, convert(varchar, d, 101) from aaa`. If you want a solution you need to extend the question and show in **SQL** what is really happening.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution part 1**

Although it is possible that this solution might not completely solve your issue, if at least you can unify your dates to look similar to each other then your position should be very much improved by placing the following at the top of your query:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
```

OR

```
SET DATEFORMAT YMD
```

OR

```
SET DATEFORMAT MDY
```

*Example*

```
SELECT
    [date]
FROM
    [your_table]
```

*Points of note:*

- M means month, D means day and Y means year.
- Setting the DATEFORMAT affects both how dates appear in the result set and how dates are converted to VARCHAR and similar.
- If you don't set the DATEFORMAT then running the same stored procedure on different machines/set-ups can yield differing results.

**Solution part 2**

You can also perform some string manipulation to replace **-**, **/**, etc. with the character of your choice.

..Put the following at the top of your query:

```
DECLARE @DateSeparator NVARCHAR(1) = '/'
```

..Use the following as part of your select statement:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE([date], '/', @DateSeparator), '-', @DateSeparator)
```

*Example*

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), [date]), '/', @DateSeparator), '-', @DateSeparator) AS [date]
FROM
    [your_table]
```

*Points of note:*

- In the above example, the date separator is set to **/**, but change the value of @DateSeparator to the date separator of your choice.

**Both solutions combined**

*Example*

```
SET DATEFORMAT YMD

SELECT
    REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), [date]), '/', @DateSeparator), '-', @DateSeparator) AS [date]
FROM
    [your_table]
```

*Points of note:*

- Replace *[your_table]* with the name of your source table.

Answer (score 0):

Since the dates were stored as `VARCHAR` instead of `DATETIME` (as they should have been) then there really is no way through SQL to determine it. Is the date '2016-02-01' February 1st or January 2nd? If you can't tell then how is any computer code going to figure it out?

Your best bet is to go back through the application(s) that have inserted or updated data in the table and try to figure out what they might have used. If users were just typing in data then that's unlikely to help, although maybe you can look for some consistencies - Janice always enters data MM/DD/YYYY, but Pierre always puts it in as DD/MM/YYYY, etc. That's probably your best bet in narrowing it down. Otherwise, you might look at other data in your system - if the table also has an `inserted_on` column for example, then maybe that and your other date would usually be within a few days of each other, etc.